# expo-mail-composer not working correctly on Android

Tags: react-native, email, expo

I just installed `expo-mail-composer` for my React Native Expo App, and it's not working like I expected it to on Android.

I'm following the documentation, calling `MailComposer.composeAsync`, and passing it a subject, body, and a single recipient.

However, it doesn't go directly to my email app (or ask me "what app would you like to complete this with" if I don't have a default assigned). Instead, it opens this ActionSheet:

[image]

The three dots are kind of strange, and there's a lot of empty space, and nothing else. It seems like a bug? It's not the behavior that the video in the Expo documentation showed, or I've seen in other apps on my device (where the mail app is opened directly). If I click one of the apps in the bottom of the actionsheet, it does open it and fill in the subject/email.

Any idea how I can get the other behavior of going directly into the email app? Am I doing something wrong?

I'm running this on a real android device, both with Expo Go and as an installed `.apk`. Versions are all recent:

```
expo: ~46.0.9,
react-native: 0.69.6,
expo-mail-composer: ~11.3.0
```

Comment: ```const mailTo = `mailto:${email}?subject=${
    subject ? '#' + subject + ' Support' : ''
  }`;
  Linking.openURL(mailTo);``` can you try this code and check if it is redirecting to gmail or not

Comment: @Nathan, please add the code, RN version, expo version, library version and if your Android attempt has been done on simulator or real device.

Comment: @FlorinDobre it's all updated, `expo: ~46.0.9`, `react-native: 0.69.6`, and `expo-mail-composer: ~11.3.0`. I'm noticing this behavior on a real Android device (OS version 13), both in the Expo Go app and after installing a built `.apk`.

Comment: Are you using a [bare react native app](https://docs.expo.dev/introduction/managed-vs-bare/#bare-workflow)?

Comment: @DialFrost, no, it's a managed Expo app

Comment: Can you try [mail-compoer-isavaiableasync](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/mail-composer/#mailcomposerisavailableasync) - even though it always runs `true` for browser and android, maybe you can quickly check it? Thanks

Comment: And are you certain you used this `import * as MailComposer from 'expo-mail-composer';
`?

Comment: @DialFrost I just verified, I am importing it that way and `isAvailableAsync` returns true.

Comment: @DialFrost no, that's not related at all-- just trying to send emails. I appreciate you looking into this, thanks!

Comment: I've spent quite a lot of time thinking and trying, but so far no luck :( It should theoretically work, but maybe your app has some issues running somehow?

Comment: @DialFrost I think it's likely just a bug for Android 13, at this point. Expo may need to add something additional to the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a [bare react native app](https://docs.expo.dev/introduction/managed-vs-bare/#bare-workflow)?

If you are, then this github page on [`expo-mail-composer` expo](https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/sdk-46/packages/expo-mail-composer) might be of help. It states that you must ensure that you have [installed and configured the `expo` package](https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-expo-modules/) before continuing.

Try the automatic installation used by the document:

```
npx install-expo-modules@latest
```

If not, since all my comments asking for tests worked for you, this may likely be a bug for Android 13, you can try reporting this to them.

Comment: No, I'm using a managed Expo app, I haven't ejected (i.e. I have no android or ios folders)